# How do I make popovers work from JSON content? (Angular, AngularStrap, JSON)

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-strap

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get angular strap popovers to work in returned JSON content (data attributes are in JSON file).

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/jVmHwIwJ0KOKCnX6QjVa?p=preview

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. thanks a bunch!!

HTML

```
<!-- Search -->
<div class="well"> 
  <p>Search the term "content"</p>
  <form role="form">
    <div my-search ng-model="selectedContent" class="form-group clearfix search">
      <input type="text" ng-model="selectedContent" ng-options="query as query.searchQuery for query in searchData" bs-typeahead="bs-typeahead" class="form-control search-field"/>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary search-btn" ng-click="updateModel()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<!-- Dynamic Content -->
<div class="well">
  <h4>{{clickedContent.contentTitle}}</h4>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in clickedContent.headlines" ng-bind-html="item.headline"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JSON

```
      [
        {
            "contentId": 1,
            "searchQuery": "Content set 1 dummy query vestibulum abcdefghijklmnop",
            "contentTitle": "Pretaining to content set 1",
            "popoverTitle": "Query info",
            "popoverContent": "Interesting info about query",
            "headlines": [
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#' data-placement='bottom', data-trigger='hover' data-title='Headline details' data-content='details about headline' bs-popover>1st headline in content set 1</a>"
                },
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#' data-placement='bottom', data-trigger='hover' data-title='Headline details' data-content='details about headline' bs-popover>2nd headline in content set 1</a>"
                },
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#' data-placement='bottom', data-trigger='hover' data-title='Headline details' data-content='details about headline' bs-popover>3rd headline in content set 1</a>"
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            "contentId": 2,
            "searchQuery": "Content set 2 dummy query vestibulum abcdefghijklmnop",
            "contentTitle": "Pretaining to content set 2",
            "popoverTitle": "Query info",
            "popoverContent": "Interesting info about query",
            "headlines": [
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#' data-placement='bottom', data-trigger='hover' data-title='Headline details' data-content='details about headline' bs-popover>1st headline in content set 2</a>"
                },
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#' data-placement='bottom', data-trigger='hover' data-title='Headline details' data-content='details about headline' bs-popover>2nd headline in content set 2<a/>"
                },
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#' data-placement='bottom', data-trigger='hover' data-title='Headline details' data-content='details about headline' bs-popover>3rd headline in content set 2</a>"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "contentId": 3,
            "searchQuery": "Content set 3 dummy query vestibulum abcdefghijklmnop",
            "contentTitle": "Pretaining to content set 3",
            "popoverTitle": "Query info",
            "popoverContent": "Interesting info about query",
            "headlines": [
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#' data-placement='bottom', data-trigger='hover' data-title='Headline details' data-content='details about headline' bs-popover>1st headline in content set 3</a>"
                },
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#' data-placement='bottom', data-trigger='hover' data-title='Headline details' data-content='details about headline' bs-popover>2nd headline in content set 3</a>"
                },
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#' data-placement='bottom', data-trigger='hover' data-title='Headline details' data-content='details about headline' bs-popover>3rd headline in content set 3</a>"
                }
            ]
        },
            {
            "contentId": 4,
            "searchQuery": "Content set 4 dummy query vestibulum abcdefghijklmnop",
            "contentTitle": "Pretaining to content set 4",
            "popoverTitle": "Query info",
            "popoverContent": "Interesting info about query",
            "headlines": [
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#' data-placement='bottom', data-trigger='hover' data-title='Headline details' data-content='details about headline' bs-popover>1st headline in content set 4</a>"
                },
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#' data-placement='bottom', data-trigger='hover' data-title='Headline details' data-content='details about headline' bs-popover>2nd headline in content set 4</a>"
                },
                {
                  "headline": "<a href='#' data-placement='bottom', data-trigger='hover' data-title='Headline details' data-content='details about headline' bs-popover>3rd headline in content set 4</a>"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

JS

```
            var app = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'mgcrea.ngStrap'])
            .config(function ($typeaheadProvider) {
              angular.extend($typeaheadProvider.defaults, {
                template: 'ngstrapTypeahead.html',
                container: 'body'
              }); 
            });

            app.directive('mySearch', function(){
              return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel){
                  ngModel.$render = function(){
                     if (angular.isObject($scope.selectedContent)) {
                       $scope.clickedContent = $scope.selectedContent;
                     }
                  }
                   $scope.updateModel = function() {
                     $scope.clickedContent = $scope.selectedContent;
                  }
                }
              }

            })

            function MainController($scope, $templateCache, $http) {

              $scope.selectedContent = '';

              $http.get('searchData.json').then(function(response){
                $scope.searchData = response.data;
                return $scope.searchData;
              });

            };
```

Comment: Is it just me or is the example script actually working? Maybe you might want to point out which popovers you're talking about... and even more important where they should be.

Comment: sorry! the demo is complex. The popovers should appear on the headlines after the search is made. The popovers in the typeahead / autosuggest are working great because they aren't coming from the json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that AngularJS, for the sake of your clients' security, automatically sanitizes HTML input in the `ng-bind-html` attribute. It automatically removes any potentially malicious attributes, such as JS events, data prefixed attributes, the `id` attribute (possibly to prevent conflicts...), and `style`.

The documentation shows [how to bypass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/%24sanitize) this auto-sanitization.

In essence:

1. Add a method of any name to your `$scope` in your `MainController`.
2. Use `$templateCache.trustAsHtml(<html>)` to return raw HTML.
3. Call that function in the `ng-bind-html` attribute instead to retrieve the raw HTML.

Unfortunately I am not very experienced with AngularJS and couldn't get it to work in your example. (I don't know how to pass a more or less dynamic variable to the function, I had hoped `ng-bind-html=\"rawHtml(item.headline)\"` would've been good enough, but it wasn't.)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I got the data attributes to appear in the html now, but it still won't work :( possibly an instantiation issue

Comment: if you inspect, you can see the attributes are there but the popover script doesn't seem to be running

Comment: @MuddyMudSkipper I suppose you would need to somehow tell AngularJS to rescan a portion of the HTML.

Comment: @MuddyMudSkipper Quick update: refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile to learn how to process the snippet with AngularJS. I do not have enough time right now to go through the documentation myself, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are want.  if so, You are welcome :)

[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/uZJPm4AyrNrmu9F5U3X4?p=preview)

basically 2 things I did.  I don't like to send data to a function for unsafe-html, a better way is to make a filter and pipe date through that.. much nicer as you can do it inline without sending them to a function.  I called this filter "unsafe"   its in your app.js

```
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});
```

Second..  like someone menitioned above in comments, just because you can "render" it doesn't mean that its been compiled..   so you have to run a compile directive to reprocess the rendered HTML and turn that into code we care about.  I called that directive "compile-template"

```
app.directive('compileTemplate', function($compile, $parse){
 return {
link: function(scope, element, attr){
  var parsed = $parse(attr.ngBindHtml);
  function getStringValue() { return (parsed(scope) || '').toString(); }

        //Recompile if the template changes
        scope.$watch(getStringValue, function() {
            $compile(element, null, -9999)(scope);  //The -9999 makes it skip directives so that we do not recompile ourselves
          });
      }         
    }
  });
```

and you would write your "dynamic content" like this:

```
    <!-- Dynamic Content -->
<div class="well">
  <h4>{{clickedContent.contentTitle}}</h4>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in clickedContent.headlines" ng-bind-html="item.headline | unsafe" compile-template></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

now you can see the example works.

please give rep if this helped!  thanks!!!